# Installed a module, broke my site. And now I have no way to turn it off

Tags: 8, drush

I'm still wrapping my head around Drupal 8 and installing modules during my learning process. Now I installed this module: https://github.com/iwhitcomb/foobar and it totally broke my site:

[image]

In Drupal 7 I used to be able to just goto the terminal and do a **drush sqlc** and manually update the modules table in the database to disable it. But in Drupal 8 there is no modules table for me to make edits.

- How do I disable this new module I installed via the drush command line? (drush pm-uninstall doesn't work as it throws the same error in the shell)

Comment: You might get away with just deleting the contents of the foobar.module file, as in empty it out altogether, and `drush cr all`. If that works you can just uninstall the module and bin it

Comment: That's why you backup your site before installing non drupal.org modules. Did you really expect a 3 year old module to work on D8 that came out very late last year? That must of been like a D8 Alpha module.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the module folder and the site will work again. And do a clear cache. I'm not sure if it leaves any orphaned entries in the Database. If so, how would one delete them?